# Initialize Backbone Models based on another Backbone Model

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js, backbone-model

I have a `config.json` that I am going to load into my app as a Backbone Model like:

```
var Config = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        base: ''
    },
    url: 'config.json'
});
```

Other models should be dependent on some data contained in `Config` like:

```
var ModelA = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        //this.url should be set to Config.base + '/someEndpoint';
    }
});
```

In above example, `ModelA`'s `url` property is dependent on `Config`'s `base` property's value.

How do I go about setting this up properly in a Backbone app?

Comment: One way is override [`Backbone.sync`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync)

Comment: @hindmost A simple code sample would be appreciated. I am new to Backbone. Thanks.

Comment: Here can be no simple samples. However I suggest to look at [my JS app](https://github.com/hindmost/jslogflush-manager), [where](https://github.com/hindmost/jslogflush-manager/blob/master/manager.js#L5) Backbone.sync overriding is used for simliar task as your.

Comment: @hindmost very nice, Ibrahim this is your answer. Alternatively you can use `backbone-associations` or `backbone-relational` to accomplish the same thing more generally. But the strategy is good - he says if missing dependencies, return `false` from `sync`, and otherwise compose it from them.

Comment: @tacos_tacos_tacos If I use `backbone-associations` for example then I would just make a 1:1 association between `Config` and `ModelA` and when fetching for `ModelA` `Config` will also be fetched and available to `ModelA` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it, your basic questions are:

- How will we get an instance of the configuration model?
- How will we use the configuration model to set the dependent model's `url`?
- How can we make sure we don't use the `url` function on the dependent model too early?

There are a lot of ways to handle this, but I'm going to suggest some specifics so that I can just provide guidance and code and "get it done," so to speak.

I think the best way to handle the first problem is to make that configuration model a singleton. I'm going to provide code from [backbone-singleton](https://github.com/ryanbeard/backbone-singleton/blob/master/src/backbone-singleton.js) GitHub page below, but I don't want the answer to be vertically long until I'm done with the explanation, so read on...

```
var MakeBackboneSingleton = function (BackboneClass, options) { ... }
```

Next, we make a singleton `AppConfiguration` as well as a `deferred` property taking advantage of `jQuery`. The result of `fetch` will provide `always(callback)`, `done(callback)`, etc.

```
var AppConfiguration = MakeBackboneSingleton(Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        base: null
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.deferred = this.fetch();
    },
    url: function() {
        return 'config.json'
    }
}));
```

Now, time to define the dependent model `DependentModel` which looks like yours. It will call `AppConfiguration()` to get the instance.

Note that because of `MakeBackboneSingleton` the follow is all `true`:

```
var instance1 = AppConfiguration();
var instance2 = new AppConfiguration();
instance1 === instance2; // true
instance1 === AppConfiguration() // true
```

The model will automatically `fetch` when provided an `id` but only *after* we have completed the `AppConfiguration`'s fetch. Note that you can use `always`, `then`, `done`, etc.

```
var DependentModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        AppConfiguration().deferred.then(function() {
            if (this.id)
                this.fetch();
        });
    },
    url: function() {
        return AppConfiguration().get('base') + '/someEndpoint';
    }
});
```

Now finally, putting it all together, you can instantiate some models.

```
var newModel = new DependentModel();   // no id => no fetch

var existingModel = new DependentModel({id: 15}); // id => fetch AFTER we have an AppConfiguration
```

The second one will auto-fetch as long as the `AppConfiguration`'s fetch was successful.

Here's `MakeBackboneSingleton` for you (again from the GitHub repository):

```
var MakeBackboneSingleton = function (BackboneClass, options) {
    options || (options = {});

    // Helper to check for arguments. Throws an error if passed in.
    var checkArguments = function (args) {
        if (args.length) {
            throw new Error('cannot pass arguments into an already instantiated singleton');
        }
    };

    // Wrapper around the class. Allows us to call new without generating an error.
    var WrappedClass = function() {
        if (!BackboneClass.instance) {
            // Proxy class that allows us to pass through all arguments on singleton instantiation.
            var F = function (args) {
                return BackboneClass.apply(this, args);
            };

            // Extend the given Backbone class with a function that sets the instance for future use.
            BackboneClass = BackboneClass.extend({
                __setInstance: function () {
                    BackboneClass.instance = this;
                }
            });

            // Connect the proxy class to its counterpart class.
            F.prototype = BackboneClass.prototype;

            // Instantiate the proxy, passing through any arguments, then store the instance.
            (new F(arguments.length ? arguments : options.arguments)).__setInstance();
        }
        else {
            // Make sure we're not trying to instantiate it with arguments again.
            checkArguments(arguments);
        }

        return BackboneClass.instance;
    };

    // Immediately instantiate the class.
    if (options.instantiate) {
        var instance = WrappedClass.apply(WrappedClass, options.arguments);

        // Return the instantiated class wrapped in a function so we can call it with new without generating an error.
        return function () {
            checkArguments(arguments);

            return instance;
        };
    }
    else {
        return WrappedClass;
    }
};
```

Comment: Isn't there any elegant solution to this? FTR, [this](https://github.com/Ibrahim-Islam/gh-blog/blob/master/app/app.js#L32-L40) is currently how I am doing. Passing in `config` after loading it through Models' constructors.

Comment: The slicker ways will involve overriding the `fetch` or `sync` or `save` or `delete` directly.

Comment: If you would like I can try to show you a way of doing that.

Comment: If its not trouble then code samples are always helpful